# How can i restrict all regions except one for all services using SCP in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can i restrict all regions except one for all services and actions using SCP in aws. Below SCP is not working.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-west-1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Service Control Policy (SCP) to allow or disallow actions and resources. AWS documentation has an example policy for denying access based on the requested region - [see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-requested-region.html).

Alternatively, below is a policy that will restrict services to a specified region (NOTE - Change the region(s) as desired)

Firstly, specify an ALLOW policy that allows actions in the region(s) you wish to use.

Secondly, specify a DENY policy denies all actions in all other regions. (Notice the StringNotEquals)

Here is a policy that uses the NotAction element with the Deny effect, which explicitly denies access to all of the actions not listed in the statement.

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllOutsideRequestedRegions",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "cloudfront:*",
                "iam:*",
                "route53:*",
                "support:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "us-east-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

CAUTION! This policy does not allow any actions. Use this policy in combination with other policies that allow specific actions..

AWS provides some example other example policies that may of be of use to customize the policy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples_general.html#example-scp-deny-region

Comment: Its showing the following error when i created the policy                                                       "The provided policy document does not meet the requirements of the specified policy type."

Comment: @kirti I updated my answer to include a policy that is provided by AWS for this. 
Please read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-requested-region.html   as referenced.